# SQS FIFO Queue Only Receiving One Message Using BOTO send_message

Tags: python, boto, amazon-sqs

I am trying to run a process which sends a series of messages to an SQS FIFO queue for a set of devices we have on hand every n seconds:

```
while 1:
    for i in range(0, len(device_list)):
        print("Putting message on queue for {}".format(device_list[i]))

        resp = sqs.send_message(
            QueueUrl=url,
            MessageAttributes={
                'device': {'DataType': 'String', 'StringValue': device_list[i]},
                'start': {'DataType': 'Number', 'StringValue': stime},
                'end': {'DataType': 'Number', 'StringValue': etime}
            },
            MessageBody=(
                'SQS message test'
            ),
            MessageGroupId=id
        )

   sleep(n)
```

Currently testing with just 20 devices. The problem I'm having is that only the first message I send is being received by the FIFO queue (checked the SQS console directly, the MessagesAvailable attribute says 1). I don't have the same problem with a Standard queue (MessagesAvailable attribute says 20), but ordering is important, so a FIFO queue is the way to go for my purposes.

I'm new to SQS, so I'm unsure if there's a problem with my queue configuration (using default settings), if it's just a feature of SQS FIFO queues, or whether I'm using the boto library correctly. Is there something I'm missing or doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no experience with this library, however reading the docs [here](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Queue.send_message) leads me to believe a possible issue could be the lack of providing a `MessageDeduplicationId`.  Particularly, the following text:

> - You may provide a MessageDeduplicationId explicitly.
> - If you aren't able to provide a MessageDeduplicationId and you enable    ContentBasedDeduplication for your queue, Amazon SQS uses a SHA-256
>     hash to generate the MessageDeduplicationId using the body of the
>     message (but not the attributes of the message).

Without seeing the rest of your code I cannot tell if `ContentBasedDeduplication` is active. If it is, since it hashes on the body of the message sent and your message body never changes, you may be continually overwriting the previous message in the queue.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. I had enabled ContentBasedDeduplication for the queue. Turning it off and specifying a unique MessageDeduplicationId for each message sent did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @DukeKong Great - glad it helped.  If you wouldn't mind accepting the answer I'd appreciate it :)